# Rosout leaks file descriptors

Tags: ros, rosout

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is weird that when I launch my ros program my os alert "too many files open". By using "lsof", I found rosout node has numerous sockets with "can't identify protocol"(as the following img shows). How did this happen?

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250393/rosout-leaks-file-descriptors/) by [nansmallgong](https://answers.ros.org/users/28852/nansmallgong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2016-12-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since these are socket file descriptors, it looks like rosout has a lot of open sockets. ROS creates a socket for each connection between a publisher and a subscriber, so there can be a lot of file descriptors involved, but even on robots with hundreds of nodes this isn't usually a problem.

You may be able to tell what these open sockets are connected to and what state they're in with `netstat -lp`. The `-l` option lists open sockets, and the `-p` option lists the process that owns that socket.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-12-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nansmallgong](https://answers.ros.org/users/28852/nansmallgong/) on 2016-12-21**:
the problem is caused by rosout do not release file descriptor correctly when a node exit with any error. As what I describe  [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/250494/how-to-collectly-shutdown-a-rosnode/)

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-11-02**:
I had some time to dig into this more deeply and have a proposed fix here: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/1214